# inline table valued functions in sql server doesn't return data

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I created a table [EMPLOYEE_DATEOFBIRTH] named

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_DATEOFBIRTH  (ID int primary key not null, 
NAME nvarchar(20) not null,
DATE_OF_BIRTH DATETIME2(7) not null, 
GENDER nvarchar(10) not null,
DEP_ID int not null)
```

and inserted data to this table.

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_DATEOFBIRTH  (ID, NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH,GENDER,DEP_ID) VALUES (1,'Jack','1980-12-30 00:00:00.000','MALE',1)

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_DATEOFBIRTH (ID, NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH,GENDER,DEP_ID) VALUES (2,'Ann','1982-09-01 12:02:36.260','FEMALE',2)
```

Then I created a function which returns list of employee by gender

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnEmployeeByGender (@Gender nvarchar)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN 
        (SELECT ID, NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH,GENDER,DEP_ID 
        FROM EMPLOYEE_DATEOFBIRTH
        WHERE GENDER=@Gender)
```

to execute this function I use the query but it doesn't return anything

```
SELECT * FROM fnEmployeeByGender('MALE')
```

what may be reason for this? thanks in advance.

Comment: mysql <> sql-server, please don't tag products not involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is here: `@Gender nvarchar`. If you don't specify a length for an `nvarchar`, it defaults to one. So you are only searching for `GENDER = 'M'`. Solve it by giving a length: `@Gender nvarchar(10)`.